How do I get my computer to recognise my keyboard?
Recently, I have installed debian 12 on my MSI 15 C7U laptop, everything was working correctly...except the keyboard.
My keyboard is detected in the GRUB menu, I can write, delete etc, however after launching debian it's not possible to use the keyboard which is disturbing...
During the launching I've found some information such as :

object-220) 0.261663l ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Fa i lure creat ing naned
object [Y_SB.PCI0.G PPS.RTL&1. AE ALREADY_ EXISTS (20320391-dsu
load2-926) I 0.2616711 ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During nane
lookup/catalog (202203 31/sobject-220) I 1.1647001 atkbd serio0:
Failed to enable keyboard on isa0060-serioo JUY 1.45425?1 hub 6-0:1.0:
config failed, hub doesn't have an portst (err -19) 1.7663101 nouveau
0000:01:00.0: firmare: failed to load nvidiarga107 nudec^s 1.?863391
firmuare_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/firmware for _infornatio I
1.7863581 nouveau 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load nu

Could you please help me to solve this problem ?
Thank you in advance !

As strange as it may seem, you may need to install Nvidia proprietary drivers.

According to this, https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/19bvpwd/linux_on_a_msi_bravo_15_c7v_my_first_deep_dive_on/, kernel 6.4 or later is needed.

Ok I'm going to try to install another Linux distro.
